# Vue close modal from a button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using `bootstrap-vue` as for the modal. When I click on button `OPEN MODAL` it opens the modal which contains footer button as `OK` and `CANCEL`. These buttons closes the modal, as its pre defined code from bootstrap-vue.

I tried to add button inside the modal called `CLOSE MODAL USING THIS BUTTON`, which is suppose to close the modal but it does not. Is there a way to make `CLOSE MODAL USING THIS BUTTON` to close out from modal?

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <b-button v-b-modal.modal-scrollable variant="info" v-on:click="opensModal">Open Modal</b-button>

  <b-modal id="modal-scrollable" scrollable title="Waiver Legal" v-show="!displayModal">
    <p class="my-4">
      "Contains modal detail"
    </p>

      <b-button variant="info" data-dismiss="modal-scrollable" v-on:click="closeModal">CLOSE USING THIS BUTTON</b-button>
      <br>

    </b-modal>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    clickOnButton: true,
    displayModal: true
  },
  methods: {
    opensModal(){
     this.clickOnButton = false; <!-- it opens the modal -->
    },
    closeModal(){
        this.displayModal = false; <!-- it does not close -->
    }
  }
})
```

Below is the link above code on `JSFIDDLE`

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/z1ndL65r/18/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `this.$bvModal.hide(id)` provided by bootstrap-vue.

So instead of...

```
<b-button variant="info" data-dismiss="modal-scrollable" v-on:click="closeModal">CLOSE USING THIS BUTTON</b-button>
```

do this instead...

```
<b-button variant="info" @click="$bvModal.hide('modal-scrollable')">CLOSE USING THIS BUTTON</b-button>
```

This way, you don't need the extra `close modal` method.

**Edit**

Actually you don't need the entire `method` block.
You can as well take out the data items.

Your code should work fine with just this...

```
<div id="app">
  <b-button v-b-modal.modal-scrollable variant="info" >Open this Modal</b-button>

  <b-modal id="modal-scrollable" scrollable title="Waiver Legal" v-show="!displayModal">
    <p class="my-4">
      "Contains modal detail"
    </p>

      <b-button variant="info" @click="$bvModal.hide('modal-scrollable')">CLOSE USING THIS BUTTON</b-button>
      <br>

    </b-modal>
</div>
```

Script...

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

Isn't that a lot cleaner? ;D

Answer (score 1):

Insted I have used another solution the `v-model` property for the b-modal for showing and hide the modal.

```
<div id="app">
  <b-button @click="openModal()" variant="info" >Open this Modal</b-button>

  <b-modal id="modal-scrollable" scrollable title="Waiver Legal" v-modal="popUp">
    <p class="my-4">
      "Contains modal detail"
    </p>

      <b-button variant="info" @click="closeModal()">CLOSE USING THIS BUTTON</b-button>
      <br>

    </b-modal>
</div>
```

...And inside script create methods

```
openModal(){
  this.popUp = true;
}

closeModal(){
  this.popUp = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm giving a solution in plain javascript. I used Vue js and I don't want to use jQuery along with Vue.

```
document.querySelector('#modalid').classList.remove('show');
document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('modal-open');
const mdbackdrop = document.querySelector('.modal-backdrop');
if (mdbackdrop){
   mdbackdrop.classList.remove('modal-backdrop', 'show');
 }
```